# -bash: : command not found when launching the shell in Mac OSX

Tags: macos, shell, bash

Lately I tried to made some changes to paths in my `.bash_profile.` 
After I tried to validate these changes with `source .bash_profile` and got `-bash: : command not found`, 
 I have also noticed that when I open the shell, before the execution of any command, it stands already "-bash: : command not found"... 
Obviously, changes made to .bash_profile weren't taken into consideration by the system niether... 
Please, help! I guess that I messed with the .bash_profile too much, have no idea how to fix it...

Contents of .bash_profile:

```
cat .bash_profile
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
##
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-03-24_at_12:05:55: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
### Your previous /Users/usrname/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/usrname/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2014-03-24_at_12:05:55
##export PATH="/Users/usrname/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
# added by Anaconda 1.9.1 installer
##Additional binary folders
export PATH=/Users/usrname/TreeTagger/cmd:$PATH
export PATH= /Users/usrname/TreeTagger/bin:$PATH
export UIMA_HOME= $/Users/usrname/apache-uima
export PATH=$PATH:$UIMA_HOME/bin
export HEIDELTIME_HOME='/Users/usrname/Downloads/heideltime-kit/'
export TREETAGGER_HOME='/Users/usrname/TreeTagger'
source $HEIDELTIME_HOME/metadata/setenv
```

Updated contents of .bash_profile:

```
cat .bash_profile
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
##
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-03-24_at_12:05:55: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
### Your previous /Users/usrname/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/usrname/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2014-03-24_at_12:05:55
##export PATH="/Users/usrname/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
# added by Anaconda 1.9.1 installer
##Additional binary folders
export PATH="/Users/usrname/TreeTagger/cmd:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/usrname/TreeTagger/bin:$PATH"
export UIMA_HOME="/Users/usrname/apache-uima"
export PATH=$PATH:$UIMA_HOME/bin
export HEIDELTIME_HOME="/Users/usrname/Downloads/heideltime-kit/"
export TREETAGGER_HOME="/Users/usrname/TreeTagger"
source $HEIDELTIME_HOME/metadata/setenv
```

Full shell output after last quotes' correction:

```
Last login: Thu Jul 31 19:07:05 on ttys000
-bash: : command not found
usr:~ usrname$ cat .bash_profile
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
##
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-03-24_at_12:05:55: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
### Your previous /Users/usrname/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/usrname/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2014-03-24_at_12:05:55
##export PATH="/Users/usrname/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
# added by Anaconda 1.9.1 installer
##Additional binary folders
export PATH="/Users/usrname/TreeTagger/cmd:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/usrname/TreeTagger/bin:$PATH"
export UIMA_HOME="/Users/usrname/apache-uima"
export PATH="$PATH:$UIMA_HOME/bin"
export HEIDELTIME_HOME="/Users/usrname/Downloads/heideltime-kit/"
export TREETAGGER_HOME="/Users/usrname/TreeTagger"
source $HEIDELTIME_HOME/metadata/setenv


usr:~ usrname$ source .bash_profile
-bash: : command not found
```

Edit with echo commands:

```
  cat .bash_profile
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
##
# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-03-24_at_12:05:55: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
### Your previous /Users/usrname/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/usrname/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2014-03-24_at_12:05:55
##export PATH="/Users/usrname/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
# added by Anaconda 1.9.1 installer
##Additional binary folders
export PATH="/Users/usrname/TreeTagger/cmd:$PATH"
export PATH="/Users/usrname/TreeTagger/bin:$PATH"
export UIMA_HOME="/Users/usrname/apache-uima"
export PATH="$PATH:$UIMA_HOME/bin"
export HEIDELTIME_HOME="/Users/usrname/Downloads/heideltime-kit/"
export TREETAGGER_HOME="/Users/usrname/TreeTagger"
echo before
source $HEIDELTIME_HOME/metadata/setenv
echo after


usr:~ usrname$ source .bash_profile
-bash: : command not found
usr:~ usrname$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
```

Edit +bash version:

```
echo $BASH_VERSION
3.2.51(1)-release
usr:~ usrname$ source ./.bash_profile
-bash: : command not found
```

Edit +after set -x was added to .bash_profile:

```
usr:~ usrname$ source ./.bash_profile
++ $'\016'
-bash: : command not found
++ update_terminal_cwd
++ local 'SEARCH= '
++ local REPLACE=%20
++ local PWD_URL=file://usr.local/Users/usrname
++ printf '\e]7;%s\a' file://usr.local/Users/usrname
```

Comment: We can't tell without seeing what you added to your `.bash_profile`. Did you change the value of `$PATH`? Perhaps you clobbered the existing value rather than adding to it.

Comment: You still don't have double quotes on two of your `export PATH=...` lines. Is it possible that your original `$PATH` includes a directory whose name contains a space character? Add the quotes and see what happens.

Comment: I corrected the quotes - doesn't work. What do you mean by "original $PATH"? Sorry, I'm not good at all these bash things((

Comment: By "original `$PATH` I mean the value that `$PATH` had before your `.bash_profile` script started running. It's likely the error occurs in `$HEIDELTIME_HOME/metadata/setenv`, which we haven't seen. Try temporarily adding `echo before` and `echo after` before and after the `source` command. Also try `echo "$PATH"` after sourcing `.bash_profile`.

Comment: That's weird. Some more things to try: `echo $BASH_VERSION` (to make sure you're running bash). Change `source .bash_profile` to `source ./.bash_profile`. Temporarily add `set -x` to the top of your `.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
export PATH= /Users/usrname/TreeTagger/bin:$PATH
```

is the problem. In a variable assignment, including an `export`, you can't have spaces around the `=`. With the added space, it sets `$PATH` to the empty string.

Change it to:

```
export PATH=/Users/usrname/TreeTagger/bin:$PATH
```

For safety, you should add double quotes:

```
export PATH="/Users/usrname/TreeTagger/bin:$PATH"
```

just in case there are any special characters in the value of `$PATH`.

You have the same problem with `UIMA_HOME`.

**UPDATE :**

Based on later comments, you appear to have a stray control character in your `.bash_profile`. With `set -x` it's displayed as `$'\016'`. bash tries to treat that as a command name, and not surprisingly is unable to find it. Edit your `.bash_profile` and delete that character.

(The other errors needed to be corrected anyway.)

Comment: The `UIMA_HOME` setting line also needs the stray `$` removed.

Comment: @user3241376: Please update your question to show the new contents of your `.bash_profile`. (I suggest leaving the old contents in place for comparison.)

Comment: I didn't know how to find this \016 character, so I just retyped the whole .bash_profile manually, and replaced the old contents with it. It works! Without any double quotes. Thank you)

Comment: @user3241376: You should still use the double quotes. Omitting them is a dangerous habit which will bite you when you don't expect it.